# extract all records in pivot table

Tags: php, laravel

In my database I have many to many relation between notifications and statuses table. So the pivot table stored the notification_id, statuses_id and values. Now, in my model I wrote a function historysStatus, which extracts that values and created_at from pivot table

```
public function historystatus()
{
    $o_status = Status::where('name','health')->first();
    $o_response = $this->statuses()->where('status_id', $o_status->id)
    ->select('values','created_at')->first();

        if($o_response === null){
            return false;
        }


     return ['value' => $o_response->values,
             'timestamp' => $o_response->created_at];
}
```

I want to iterate through all the values and timestamps associated with a specific notification.thus in blade I wrote the for each loop to iterate through all values and created at.

```
@foreach($notes as $notification)
    <?php $notificationHealth = $notes->historystatus('health'); ?>
    <tr>   
        <td>{{ $notificationHealth['timestamp'] }}</td>                         
        <td> {{ $notificationHealth['value'] }}</td>.
    </tr>    
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

instead it gave me only the last record 4 times. Is something wrong with the sql query? I would appreciate any suggestion and ideas?

Comment: use $notificationHealth = $notification->historystatus('health'); instead of $notificationHealth = $notes->historystatus('health');

Comment: typo error even with that change it doesn't do the job

Comment: Why is this tagged with CakePHP? The code looks like Laravel...

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `foreach` try using `$notification->historystatus('health');` instead of `$notes->historystatus('health');`

```
    @foreach($notes as $notification)
    <?php $notificationHealth = $notification->historystatus('health'); ?>
    <tr>   
        <td>{{ $notificationHealth['timestamp'] }}</td>                         
        <td> {{ $notificationHealth['value'] }}</td>.
    </tr>    
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function history($s_type)
    {
        if (!in_array($s_type, ['speed', 'health'])){
            return false;
        }

        $o_status = Status::where('name', strval($s_type))->first();
        $o_response = $this->statuses()->where('status_id', $o_status->id)
        ->select('values', 'created_at')->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get();

        if($o_response === null || $o_response->count() === 0){
            return false;
        }

        $a_ret = [];

        foreach ($o_response as $o_status) {
            $a_ret[] = [
                'value' => $o_status->values,
                'timestamp' => $o_status->created_at
            ];
        }

        return $a_ret;

    }
```

this is the simple answer i figured out. and the foreach loop in side the blade.